# How to create a rule that sends a request off to Maximo?

Tags: ibm-cloud, maximo

I created rules in Foundation -> Insights -> Analytics -> a rule, and in that rule, I set the action to send off an email when the condition was met.

What I really want to do is kick off a REST call to my Maximo server to generate a service request order.  I can do that by hand, but I can't do that through a rule.

In the documentation for Insights (http://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/iotrtinsights/index.html) it specifically states that rules and actions can be sent off to Maximo.

So it seems that only Email is supported, unless someone has figured out a way to connect to Maximo?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is not as simple to write it here at SO, but I can guide you with the following answer:

1. You can insert rows into the db of maximo
2. you can use [Maximo Integration framework](http://maximodev.blogspot.com/2012/11/introduction-to-maximo-integration-framework-mif.html)

The first option is to write insert queries, here you are able to connect to the tables using the drivers for your database. i.e. We use db2 and I can connect using [db2 jdbc](https://www.google.sr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=db2%20jdbc%20driver)

Keep in mind you should now all the tables maximo uses to edit/update/delete maximo uses when working with your own queries.

As for Maximo integration framework, there are scala of options, so it will merely depend on what the other system can export.

Comment: Thanks davejal.  It turns out for me, just making HTTP calls to the REST API, I don't really need to know about the table structure.  I just need to get to the point where I can launch an HTTP request.  Right now, I can only send an email.  

I'm thinking my question should be more about IoT Insights than about Maximo: either I need to understand more about Insights so I can configure it to talk to Maximo, or, I need to install Maximo in Bluemix.

Answer (score 0):

After consulting with IBM, it turns out that it is not currently possible to achieve this without writing a script inside Maximo, or by writing an intermediate service in Node.Red, despite the documentation.

They say that in time, this feature might be supported more directly.